# how can i use cypress on a old project?

Tags: node.js, angular, automation, cypress, version

I have an old project made in version 8.9.4 of Node.js and old angular, and I would like to start an basic automation process with Cypress, but upon installation it claims not to be compatible due to the very old version. Is there any way I can use an older, compatible version of Cypress in this project? How?

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing in E2E mode, it doesn't exactly matter about the Angular and Node versions, Cypress will only require the running page to perform tests.

If you want to compile and serve the app, Docker would be the best option since you don't really want to back-down you machine's Node version.

It may be the Angular app is already deployed to the web, in which case you don't need to use Docker.

If you are aiming to do **Component** testing, you probably can't do it with Angular v7.2

---

For reference, your Angular/Node/RxJs version compatability is [here](https://angular.io/guide/versions#before-v9)

and a docker image you might use [accelbyte/node:8.9.4-alpine-amd64](https://hub.docker.com/layers/accelbyte/node/8.9.4-alpine-amd64/images/sha256-537a8a47ddd81f46d36b5108dc2d6a6156f11cfa7b823360b69ebf2f376a7fcf?context=explore)

Overall, I strongly recommend running up-to-date Cypress, since you won't get much bug support for an older version. Even trying to find the correct documentation might be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Cypress Migration guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Nodejs-10-support), starting with Cypress 5.0, support for versions below Node.js 10 was deprecated.

I have not tried this myself, but my assumption then would be that [Cypress 4.12.1](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#4-12-1) is the latest version to support your node version. Installing that would be as simple as just specifying that when running `npm install`:

```bash
npm install cypress@4.12.1
```

However, looking at that migration guide, you'll see that Cypress comes with it's own node version and only uses the local version for installing:

> Cypress comes bundled with its own Node.js version. However, installing the cypress npm package uses the Node.js version installed on your system.

So, I think you *could* use a more modern version of Cypress by switching your node version to a more modern one, installing the modern version of Cypress you want to use, and then downgrading your node version.